# MS ACCESS: Placing a field value of current record in the e-mail "Subject"

Tags: email, ms-access, field, subject

I have the following code to send a report (pdf) as an e-mail. 
The code works fine! However, i would like a field of the current record that im sending to be part of the emails subject. I have tried a bunch of things but nothing works.

The current subject is **"Order is ready!"**

I would like this to be **"Order [ordernumber] is ready!"**

```
Private Sub sendesoreq_Click()

Dim stDocName As String
stDocName = "orderfinished_2"

DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , "[orderID] = " & Me.orderID

DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "orderfinished_2", ".pdf",                            
"mymail@gmail.com", , , "Order is ready!", "Success! The 
following order is ready for shipment. Thank you!", False
Me.orderstatuscombo.Value = "ESO request sent"
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use string concatenate to insert your field

Instead of :

```
 "Order is ready!"
```

Use

```
 "Order #" & Me.orderID & " is ready!"
```

Comment: omg you helped me out for the second time today.
Your contribution i well noticed. Thanks alot!

Comment: No problem - if it was considered the answer you were looking for, please mark it as such. And welcome to Stack Overflow - I've received lots of help from others here so I try to help who I can too.